# Error:SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined firts years student

Tags: php, html, pdo, error-handling

I am having trouble of finding why my code is not working . I tried to look up on the internet but I can't seem to find the error
Here's my function

```
<?php 
    include "gar-connect.php";
    try { 
        $stmt = $conn->prepare ("INSERT INTO gebruiker(voornaam,achternaam,gebruikerid,wachtwoord,) 
                                 VALUES (:voornaam, :achternaaam, :gebruikerid,:wachtwoord)");
        $stmt->bindParam(':voornaam ',$voornaam);
        $stmt->bindParam(':achternaam ',$achternaam);
        $stmt->bindParam(':gebruikerid ',$gebruikerid);
        $stmt->bindParam(':wachtwoord ',$wachtwoord);
 
        if(isset($_REQUEST['voornaam'])){
            $voornaam = $_POST['voornaam'];
            $achternaam = $_POST['achternaam'];
            $gebruikerid= $_POST['gebruikerid'];
            $wachtwoord= $_POST['wachtwoord'];
        $stmt->execute();
        header('location: select.php');
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
         echo "Error:" .$e->getMessage();
    }
    $conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: There is an extra `,` in `wachtwoord,)`, try this first.

Comment: @Felippe Duarte the variables are stmt->bindparam after or not ??

Comment: @merrin K what was wrong with it what do i have to do with the editet code??

Comment: Why you re adding *spaces* to parameter names?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte FYI that's how it's supposed to work

Comment: @merrin K your code and my code looks the same

Comment: Code edited is not the answer, I have improved the formatting of your code, the answer will be bellow the comment section